# Adobe Acrobat is interfering with PDF files shown with WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit, acrobat

I am using the WebView class from WebKit to display a PDF document.

I am creating an  instance of NSURLRequest and passing it the URL to the PDF.

**The PDF document does not display when Adobe Acrobat is installed** on the system. Uninstalling Acrobat fixes the issue.

When Acrobat is installed, a white screen with a loading bar is shown:
[image]

When Acrobat is not installed, the PDF is shown:

[image]

How can I fix this and get it to work with Acrobat installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access the `preferences` property of the WebView, and disable plugins.

```
[webView.preferences setPlugInsEnabled:NO];
```

This will disable the Acrobat plugin.